# Jquery update "intterupts" Admin Menu

Tags: javascript

Drupal 7 system. minimalistic, almost no modules installed and the site works fine. The problem:

From the moment I've installed the module Jquery Update, There is no more Dropdown by the Admin Menu module... Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to

```
admin/config/development/jquery_update
```

and set the Default jQuery Version to 1.8 or higher

and the Alternate jQuery version for administrative pages to 1.7 (1.5 and lower has issues with views and other modules)

Then clear your Drupal and browser cache if need be.

If you don't see these settings in jquery update ui then install the latest dev version of jquery update.

Comment: admin/config/development/jquery_update ? Sorry, I couldn't find such a folder "Admin" in my Drupal installation. Where should it be? Thx.

Comment: @Benosa That is a URL; not a folder.  It is the admin page for configuring jQuery Update.

Comment: This works for me when I'm in the admin area but when I'm logged in as an admin and viewing content not in the admin area I still have issues with errors in the JS console.

Answer (score 0):

When you first install and enable this module, it will be set to 1.10.  In my experience, almost everything will be buggy if set at 1.8 or higher.  I always have my sites set at 1.7, and that's what I would recommend to use site wide.